# Equality of limits on $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function defined on an open set $S$ containing the origin. Prove the following by $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition: If there exists: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=L,$$ 
and there exists:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y)=L_{12},$$ 
then $L=L_{12}$.

I'm trying to work out something like |$f(x,y)-L$|<$\varepsilon$, and maybe apply the triangular inequality, but got stuck on showing the details. Could somebody provide a precise proof of this property please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little groady.

There has to be an $f_1(x)=\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)$ for the definition of $L_{12}$ to make sense.  Given $\epsilon>0$, we have $|L_{12}-f_1(x)|<\epsilon$ for $|x|<\delta$ for some $\delta$.  Because $L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$, we also have $|L-f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ for $|(x,y)|<\delta_2$ for some $\delta_2$. We also have $|x|\leq |(x,y)|$.  Then 
$$|L-f_1(x)| = |L-\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)| = \lim_{y\to 0} |L-f(x,y)| \leq\epsilon \,\,{\rm whenever}\,\, |x|<\delta_2$$
The two inequalities $|L-f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ and $|L-f_1(x)| \leq\epsilon$ together then give $|L_{12}-L|<2\epsilon$.

(Here we're using a theorem that says something like $\lim F(g(y)) = F(\lim g(y))$ for all continuous $F$.  To apply this we let $F$ be the function $F(z)=|L-z|$.  We also have that if $G(x)\leq A$ for small $x$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} G(x)\leq A$ if it exists, another elementary theorem.)

Comment: If $f_1(x)=\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)$ is defined and exists, can we show the existence of $L_{12}$, if the existence of  $L_{12}$ isn't given as a property?

Comment: I don't quite understance why "Given $\epsilon>0$, we have $|L_{12}-f_1(x)|<\epsilon$ for $|x|<\delta$ for some $\delta$."

Comment: Re the first query, I think so but I'm a little tired to write that out.  Re the second query, we've adopted the notation $f_1(x)=\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)$ for all $x$, and we are told as part of the problem that $\lim_{x\to 0} \lim_{y\to0} f(x,y)$, i.e., $\lim_{x\to 0} f_1(x)$, equals $L_{12}$, whence the epsilon-delta statement you queried.