# Another version of equality of limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function defined on an open set $S$ containing the origin. Prove the following by $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition: If there exists: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)=L,$$ 
Also, $f_1(x)=\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)$ is defined and exists.

Show that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y)$$ 
exists, and if we let $$\lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{y \to 0} f(x,y)=L_{12}$$, then $L=L_{12}$.

It might appear as a stronger version of : [Equality of limits on $\varepsilon - \delta$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568640/double-limit-and-iterated-limit-on-varepsilon-delta-proof/1568710#1568710), but not sure if this could be proved. Could somebody provide a precise proof of this property please? Thanks.